# itext 5.5.11 cast exception[com.itextpdf.text.ZapfDingbatsList cannot be cast to com.itextpdf.text.ListItem]

Tags: itext, xmlworker

I have create an application for parsing html string to pdf. now its working but showing an exception.i couldnot find what is the actual issue.

XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer,
                            document, new ByteArrayInputStream(parserXHtml(page.getPageContent()).getBytes()));

```
public String parserXHtml(String html) {
    org.jsoup.nodes.Document document = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);
    document.outputSettings().syntax(org.jsoup.nodes.Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.xml);
    //document.outputSettings().charset("UTF-8");
    return document.html();
}
```

Above code used for pasring html string to pdf

error screen shot

[image: error screen shot]

Sample html contents

```
<p>This section includes assumptions that the BCP is written under.&nbsp; Some examples are below.<\/p><p><strong> General </strong><\/p><ul> <li>WolfPAC Organization Name has suffered a significant interruption of back office operations at one or more of its facilities<\/li> <li>None or not all of the branches have been affected by the same incident.<\/li> <li>Key personnel, or their designated back-ups identified in the plan, are available following a disaster.<\/li> <li>Critical employees, as listed in the individual Business Unit BCP\/BIA Worksheets and on the IT Recovery Summary, will be relocated to a contingency site.&nbsp;<\/li> <li>Connections to the core system will be made from the Contingency Sites.<\/li> <li>The contingency site(s) is\/are available and prepared according to&nbsp;the institution&rsquo;s specifications.<\/li>\t<li>Connectivity to all utilities is operational at the contingency site.<\/li>\t<li>Connectivity will be made to all branches from the contingency site.<\/li>\t<li>The network will be recovered following a disaster affecting the main data center.<\/li>\t<li>All critical suppliers and vendors are available to support the institution.&nbsp; WolfPAC Organization Name has reviewed SLAs and Business Continuity Plans for all third party resources.&nbsp; Critical resources required for business operations are available from identified suppliers or off-site storage.&nbsp;<\/li>\t<li>The BCP Plan is not intended to provide a &ldquo;business as usual&rdquo; environment but will provide for continuity of daily operations of critical applications and business functions in a scaled back environment.<\/li>\t<li>Recovery expectations have been communicated and approved by managers and the Executive Management Team and reported to the Board of Directors.<\/li>\t<li>Procedures for back-up and off-site storage of computer media and manual files have been deemed sufficient by&nbsp;the IT Department, are kept current, and the data is readily available to the contingency sites.<\/li>\t<li>Proper cooperation and resources will be provided based upon the importance of the business function to support a timely recovery.<\/li>\t<li>Team Members have the ability to designate responsibilities to other members of their department who have the expertise to execute the task(s). However, team members will be held accountable for the responsibilities being completed.<\/li>\t<li>Expenses during a disaster will be recorded in a separate disaster ledger and reported as described in each section.<\/li>\t<li>Daily operational, off-line, and recovery procedures will not be documented in this Plan. It is recommended that each department maintain any procedures critical to daily operations. These procedures should be stored off-site in a secure location and on the network if it is being backed up.&nbsp;<\/li>\t<li>Maintenance of the plan must be performed on a continuing basis, as changes to the business requirements and technology must be reflected.<\/li>\t<li>Components of the plan must be tested periodically: at least twice per year is recommended.&nbsp; Test Objectives should vary from test to test to consider various areas of the institution.<\/li>\t<li>A copy of this plan will be provided to all of the Executive Management Team, leaders of each Business Continuity Disaster Team<\/li><\/ul><br\/>"
```

Comment: Show us your HTML code. You will notice that the structure of `<ol>`/`</ol>` tags, and its `<li>`/`</li>` elements is wrong. That is: it's not structured the way iText expects it.

Comment: <p>Please attach BIA Technology Summary worksheet.<\/p><p><strong> Business Impact Analysis Assumptions: </strong><\/p><p>Unless specifically noted otherwise, the following assumptions will be made: (Samples noted below)<\/p><ul>\t<li>A workstation consists of a PC and a phone<\/li>\t<li>Connectivity to the network will be made for all users<\/li>\t<li>Access to a printer, fax, and copier will be given at the alternate processing site(s)<\/li><\/ul><p>All departments will have access to Internet, MS Office and MS Outlook (Email)<\/p><br\/>

Comment: Those `\t` things, are those actual tab characters, or literally `\t`? You really shouldn't paste code in a comment. Please update your question.

Comment: found the solution:- unused extra <ul> tag found in my html

Comment: Problem solved :D And yes, that was what I meant in my initial comment.